# TrieIntField, TrieDateField deprecated to?

Tags: solr, updates, ckan, solr8

## Clear Solr warnings and errors resulting from the deprecated classes below:

1. **TrieIntField**
   Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieIntField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
2. **TrieFloatField**
   Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieFloatField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
3. **TrieLongField**
   Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieLongField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
4. **TrieDoubleField**
   Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieDoubleField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
5. **TrieDateField**
   Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.TrieDateField]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Major Changes in schema.xml Solr 8.0 and 9.0 (Schema Changes in 8.0 and 9.0)

The following changes impact how fields behave.

Here is a table of solr deprecated fields and what is being used in solr 8.0

| Deprecated | Instead Use |
| --- | --- |
| CurrencyField | CurrencyFieldType |
| EnumField | EnumFieldType |
| LatLonType | LatLonPointSpatialField |
| TrieDateField | DatePointField |
| TrieDoubleField | DoublePointField |
| TrieFloatField | FloatPointField |
| TrieIntField | IntPointField |
| TrieLongField | LongPointField |
| TrieField | This field takes a type parameter to define the specific class of Trie* field to use; Use an appropriate Point Field type instead. |
| LowerCaseTokenizer | You are encouraged to use the LetterTokenizer and the LowerCaseFilter instead |

**Note**: Please make sure to re-index after changing any of the above for the changes to work and avoiding to get wired values.

For more information, check the solr official website for more [details here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/major-changes-in-solr-8.html)

### Deprecated Field Types in Solr 9.0

**Note**:
All **Trie*** numeric and date field types have been deprecated in favor of *Point field types. Point field types are better at range queries (speed, memory, disk), however simple field:value queries underperform relative to Trie. Either accept this, or continue to use Trie fields. This shortcoming may be addressed in a future release.

| Deprecated | Instead Use |
| --- | --- |
| CurrencyField | CurrencyFieldType |
| EnumField | EnumFieldType |
| TrieDateField | DatePointField |
| TrieDoubleField | DoublePointField |
| TrieFloatField | FloatPointField |
| TrieIntField | IntPointField |
| TrieLongField | LongPointField |
| TrieField | This field takes a type parameter to define the specific class of Trie* field to use; Use an appropriate Point Field type instead. |

**Recommended Field Types are:**

- BBoxField -> single rectangle
- BinaryField -> Binary data
- BoolField -> true or false
- CollationField -> Unicode Collation
- CurrencyFieldType -> Currencies and exchange rates.
- DateRangeField -> Date Formatting and Date Math
- DenseVectorField -> Dense Vector Search
- DatePointField -> Date field.
- DoublePointField -> Double field (64-bit IEEE floating point)
  and many more..
  You can read more [details here](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/field-types-included-with-solr.html)